# volttron install central and sub instance

Tags: volttron

I have a question about install volttron instance.

I had install two instance volttron ( one is installed raspberry pi3 and the other is installed Virtual Box).

I started two instance and then access Cetnral Web Page.

I checked platform(central), but cannot check sub instance.

I set the subinstance preference as shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ioOM.png)
How can you solve the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please find the demonstration for implementing multiple instances:
http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/4.1/devguides/walkthroughs/VOLTTRON-Central-Demo.html#remote-platform-configuration

One of the critical points to consider is "these instances need to have unique addresses". please make sure to give for every instance (i.e. raspberry pi3 and Virtual Box) a different address.

You might also need to check additional factors described: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48492084/9341589)

Thanks,
KJ